# Django custom 404 page not recognized

Tags: django, django-templates

I've placed a custom 404.html page in my root templates directory, but whenever an invalid URL is requested, the default error page is given. Strangely in production, "Internal Server Error" is displayed, while "Not Found.
The requested resource was not found on this server." is displayed on localhost.

Debug is set to false in both cases.

app/templates/app/404.html:

```
{% extends "app/base.html" %}

{% block page_header %}
    <h1>404</h1>
    <h2>The page you requested is not available.</h2>
    <i class="far fa-meh"></i>
{% endblock page_header %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a new templates folder in the root (not in an app folder) without any sub-folders. The file is located now in `root/templates/404.html`